# How do I convert a string to custom object

Tags: java

I am lost as to how I should be converting holder to test. I receive the error Incompatible types string can not be converted to MeterReading. I am not sure what to assign r to in the constructor.

```
public void addReading(MeterReading m){
    String holder = String.valueOf(m.getReading());
    MeterReading test = holder;
    meterReadings.add(test);
}
```

MeterReading Class

```
public class MeterReading {
    private float reading;
    private String flag;


    public float getReading(){
        reading =  2;
        return reading;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime(){
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
        return date;
    }

    public String getFlag(){
        return flag;
    }
    public String getMeter(){
        return "help";
    }
    //constructor
    public MeterReading(float r,LocalDateTime date,String t, Meter m){
        reading =  r;
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on the `MeterReading` class, beside that you could create a constructor like `MeterReading(String s)`

Comment: I have provided the MeterReading class

Comment: What are you trying to do? I still do not get it. What role does `holder` play and what type does it represent in `MeterReading`?

Comment: I use holder to hold the value of a float as a string but now i need to convert that to a MeterReading object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break your code down step by step:

```
String holder = String.valueOf(m.getReading());
```

So, from an existing `MeterReading` your are getting its `reading` and convert that to a `String`.

```
MeterReading test = holder;
```

Next, your are trying to assign a `String` to a `MeterReading`. This causes a compile time error since both are completely different objects.

Currently, to create a `MeterReading` you are using the following constructor:

```
public MeterReading(float r, LocalDateTime date, String t, Meter m){
    reading = r;
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Its obvious that this constructor is not what we need if we are only given a `String` value. What you could do is to create a new constructor which accepts that as an argument and converts it back to a float:

```
public MeterReading(String holder){
    reading = Float.valueOf(holder);
}
```

This way, you can do the following: `MeterReading test = new MeterReading(holder);`

Please note that your `flag` String variable will **not** be initialized with this constructor, thus being `null`.

Comment: I am still struggling with the constructor: public MeterReading(float holder, LocalDateTime d,String t, Meter m){
   reading =  holder;
   date = d;
   flag =  t;
   Meter test =  new Meter(test.getID(),test.getBrand(),test.getType());
   test =  m;
}

Comment: What is your problem then? Please explain :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor for MeterReading, that would take a String as an argument, and then assign it to the object.

Comment: I have added the MeterReading class